# KARATE: Match each fails for Json Arrays containing URL

Tags: karate

I am trying to validate Json Arrays containing URLs using match each function. I get below error when I try to do that

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $[0], actual: 'https://swapi.co/api/films/2/', expected: ["https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/films\/2\/","https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/films\/6\/","https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/films\/3\/","https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/films\/1\/","https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/films\/7\/"], reason: actual value is not list-like
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:551)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchEquals(StepDefs.java:537)
at ?.* match each response.films == response.films(C:\Users\r0m01iu\Documents\Projects\Space_Projects\QE_Workspace\api-testing-karate\target\test-classes\examples\swapi\people.feature:19)
```

Feature File:

```
Feature: Sample project with SWAPI

Scenario: Test some scenario

Given url 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/'
When method get
Then status 200
* match each response.films == response.films
```

Comment: Apologies @PeterThomas .. that was pending from a while now!! .. I have accepted the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `match` assertion doesn't make any sense at all. Please read the docs and examples carefully. Also here are some examples that work:

```
Given url 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/'
When method get
Then status 200
* match each response.films == '#string'
* match each response.films contains 'https://swapi.co/api/films/'
* match response contains { films: '#[] #string' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter.. In this case can you suggest me on how can I assert every element in JSON Array?

Comment: @RakeshMahendrakar did you read the docs ? https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each